# Using SEO URLs with PHP when you need multiple handling pages

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

In the past I've used htaccess to intercept requests for specific pages, but I now need to be able to create a bunch of SEO-friendly URLs which will point at multiple pages and thinking this may not be as straightforward.

For instance:

```
www.domain.com/training
                  ^
        easy, as this can be pointed at a training.php page

www.domain.com/training/apple/final-cut-pro
                          ^
  trickier, since 'apple' may be dynamically created in the database,
  and the handling page for vendor training needs to be different to the 
  handling page for the specific course or the top level training page
```

So in the above example I might want to point /training at training.php, but /training/apple at vendors.php and /training/apple/final-cut-pro at products.php (and there may be deeper levels also). Add to this that there will also be /agency/xxx/xxx and /news/xx type links.

Is there a way in htaccess to look at the first part of the URL (i.e., 'training', 'news') and then 'count' the depth of the URL to figure out where it should be sent? A sort of conditional like:

```
if root = 'training' then
    if depth = 1 then
        redirect to training.php
    else if depth = 2 then
        redirect to vendor.php
    else if depth = 3 then
        redirect to product.php
else if root = 'agency' then
    etc...
```

Thanks for any help on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# depth=1
RewriteRule ^training/?$ training.php [L,NC]

# depth=2
RewriteRule ^training/[^/]+/?$ vendor.php [L,NC]

# depth=3
RewriteRule ^training/[^/]+/[^/]+/?$ product.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Elegant and simple. Thanks